# passing an XML document (fragment) as parameter to XSLT in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xslt

I want to preload an XML document (called **XMLParam**) and pass it to an XSLT processing of another document (**oXML**), as a parameter, using setParameter.

However, the XSLT does not handle it as a node, nodelist or anything, just reports [object Element]

```
oXML = XMLDoc_load(sXMLURL);
oXMLParam = XMLDoc_load(sXMLParamURL);
oXSLT = XMLDoc_load(sXSLTURL);
var oXSLTProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
oXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet(oXSLT);
oXSLTProcessor.setParameter(null,"oDocument",oXMLParam.documentElement);
var oResultDoc = oXSLTProcessor.transformToFragment(oXML, document); 


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="oDocument"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"><p>Parameter:<xsl:copy-of select="$oDocument"/></p></xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to pass in the URL of the document you want to load as the parameter value, then use the XSLT `document` function to load the document with XSLT. That way it might be possible to achieve what you want.

I am afraid http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables does not really specify in detail what kind of types a processor needs to support to be passed in from an application to a stylesheet. It sounds as if Chrome simply calls toString on the DOM element node you pass in and then XSLT works with a string and not with a node-set as you want it.

Comment: unfortunately document($sURL) also does not function in chrome